# $f$ will always reach 1 if $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)=1^-$?

Tags: limits

Suppose an algorithm A, has success probability of 10%.

One experiment is composed by a (possibly infinite) number of executions of A.
In one experiment, the success probability of at least one execution after x trials can be found by:

$P[x\ge1]=1-(\frac{90}{100})^x$ and so $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}P[x\ge1]=1^-$

So, having that in mind, can we say that every experiment will always succeed?

I would say that we can't. If we say for example that the algorithm will succeed after k tries (for any value of k), then somebody could argue that after infinite number of experiments, then there would be at least one experiment in which the algorithm A failed after k tries.

Or in another way, after infinite number of experiments, there will be at least one experiment in which A fails for infinite number of executions.

Is that right?

Comment: "Eventually" is an ambiguous term.

Comment: I have removed it, but does it make a difference?

Comment: Your question is still ambiguous.

Comment: I am kind of new to this area, can you please elaborate?

Comment: For starters, define clearly what you mean by "algorithm A will eventually succeed".

Comment: I have added some more info, removed eventually

Comment: algorithm A is not the same as running algorithm A multiple times in this context

Comment: @AntonisParagas And you still haven't defined the term. You just replaced it with another undefined term.

Comment: I think now should be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let B be the algorithm running A until it succeeds.

There are different ways of looking at this

- There is a case where B runs forever (if A keeps failing)
- The probability of this case (that B runs forever), is $0$
- For any $k$, the probability, that B will require more than $k$ calls to $A$, is greater than $0$

So depending on what you want to know, the answer will be different.

Comment: Nice, yeah i was looking if the first case was really inside the possible outcomes of an experiment